# Storing commercial files on the server

Tags: security, e-commerce

Where would you store files that are meant for sale on an e-commerce website?

Comment: are they "sensitive" information?

Comment: I wouldn't say they are sensitive information. They are just commercial files and a free access to them shouldn't be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere out of htdocs/wwwroot/etc.  You don't want anyone to link to them directly.  You should have a page/script that can read that location and send the file back.

Answer (score 1):

On a secure server in a network zone that is not directly accessible from the internet.  Your webserver can then access and retrieve files only for authorised users.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of thumb: Not in htdocs (i.e. not accessible from the internet).

What do you want to do with those files? Offer them for downloading after a customer payed? You should manage the credentials by a server sided script (e.g. a PHP script) and give that script access to the file.

Comment: Yes, the files should be available for download to users that have payed for them.